# How to tune sentiment analysis when one algorithm says positive and one negative?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I'm currently working on a project and I use [Google CNL] [1](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language) and [PyFeel] [2](https://github.com/AdilZouitine/pyFeel) to perform a sentiment analysis of a dataset.

I have read a lot of articles and tips on how to tune the classifier, but I'm more looking for some ideas on: what to do when technology 1 says positive and technology 2 says negative?

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general machine learning case, this is what ensembles are all about: taking the output of multiple models and making a decision. So there is a huge amount of literature you can read there.

When you have two models the choices will come down to:

- Sum their confidences
- Trust one more
- Get a 3rd opinion as a tie-breaker.
- Make no decision/escalate to a human

If the two models are binary classifiers then you cannot use the first idea (which would say if model A says it is +0.7 positive sentiment, and model B says it is -0.4 negative sentiment, then the sum is +0.3, so it is positive).

The second idea, with only two binary classifier models, makes your less trusted model pointless. But it is useful if you have scores to work with. Extending the previous example, if you trust model B twice as much, +0.7 + (-0.4 * 2) = -0.1.

I.e. because you trust model B more, you allow its -0.4 to override model A's +0.7, and decide it is negative.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your first idea wuth the sum and the confidence is something I can do in my project. I really appreciate your input